# Reading InMemoryUploadedFile twice

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have an `InMemoryUploadedFile` object and when I make a `.read()` on it, it will lose its content.

Is it somehow possible to read this content twice from the same object? I tried to `.copy()` it, but of course that should not work.

If it is not possible, can I somehow put the content back to the same object?

Reason for this:

In a django form, a `.prevalidation()` method would read the content, but if it does, I can' t save it later on.

Performance here is not an issue.

Comment: do something like this, 
`foo = ''`
`read_once = InMemoryUploadedFile.read() `
`foo = foo + read_once `
`#so , now you will be able to use foo as 2nd time`

Comment: With this the problem is that it' ll be a new object.

Answer (score 22):

You should be able to call `seek(0)` on the underlying file object:

```
my_file_obj.file.seek(0)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i needed.

Comment: `InMemoryUploadedFile` implements the full file interface, so you can just call `my_file_obj.seek(0)`.

Comment: As I stumbled across this issue myself, I just want to line out some background information on this. If you read() a file, the cursor is set to the end, by executing my_file.file.seek(0) you reset the cursor and can use read() again.

Answer (score 8):

Just adding to @Daniel Roseman answer.

Or you could just call **my_file_obj.open()** .
It does the same thing.

Here is the code from Django's docs

```
    class InMemoryUploadedFile(UploadedFile):
        def open(self, mode=None):
            self.file.seek(0)
            return self
```

reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/_modules/django/core/files/uploadedfile/

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a reason to not do this just because we are moving the pointer to the begging instead of letting it stay/reach the end.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing a write operation on s3 from a file source InMemoryUploadedFile. Here is the catch the file buffer i am giving to write on s3 object, it closes the file after reading. If i am to seek but it is non seekable object.

https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/256

so in python there is a deepcopy i made a copy of object, now i have two object with diffrent buffer reader

```
file_obj1 = copy.deepcopy(file_obj)
buffer1 = file_obj.file
buffer2 = file_obj1.file
```

Here file_obj is a InMemoryUploadedFile

Comment: Which Django version are you on? On Django 3.2.8, you get a TemporaryUploadedFile, which deepcopy doesn't work on.